# What could possibly be changing the access time of old backedup files?

Tags: filesystem, filemanager, tracker

I am using ubuntu 14 LTS 64 bit.

I keep backup of my source files in /var/src-backup/. I was examining the access date of all those files and it appears as though the files have been accessed at least 10 days ago. Now, some of the backups there are a year old and hasnt been viewed at all.

I was thinking that perhaps some sort of an OS program was accessing the files for some reason but if that was the case then probably the timestamps of all the files would be same(down to the exact second), right? But some of the files have been accessed 10 days ago some 3 days ago.

The files are GPG encrypted directories compressed as an archive.

No one besides me have access to my computer.
Is this normal or do i have reasons to believe that someone has been trying to read/copy/upload the files without my permission?

Answer (score 0):

File manager searching through that folder tree? Counting all files & adding up their sizes? Any indexing service?

If you disabled access times when mounting that backup (with `noatime`), then the access time shouldn't be changed (unless you modify the file I think)

Comment: are you saying that any one of that activities could have changed the access time?